# Web forms sytax to Razor sytax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor-2

I am doing NerdDinner. And I want to use Razor sytax instead of Web forms'. When I debugged the project. It said that "Model" is not defined. The whole displayed error is as below:

```
Unhandled exception at line 133, column 9 in http://localhost:52372/Dinner/Create

0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Model' is undefined
```

And it generated a file named

```
Create[dynamic]
```

What is the file mean and what is wrong with my Razor syntax.

Thanks in advance.

The original syntax

```
<script src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/Map.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  

<div id="theMap"> 
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">      
$(document).ready(function() {      
var latitude = <%=Model.Latitude%>;    
var longitude = <%=Model.Longitude%>;  

if ((latitude == 0) || (longitude == 0))          
LoadMap();   

else          
LoadMap(latitude, longitude, mapLoaded); 
}); 

function mapLoaded() {      
var title = "<%=Html.Encode(Model.Title) %>";    
var address = "<%=Html.Encode(Model.Address) %>";      
LoadPin(center, title, address);  
map.SetZoomLevel(14); 
}  
</script>
```

The Razor syntax

```
@model NerdDinner.Models.Dinner

<script src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="/Scripts/Map.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 

<div id="theMap">
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        var latitude = Model.Latitude;
        var longitude =Model.Longitude;

        if ((latitude == 0) || (longitude == 0))
            LoadMap();
        else
            LoadMap(latitude, longitude, mapLoad);    
    });

    function mapLoad()
    {

        var title = "@Html.Encode(Model.Title)"
        var address = "@Html.Encode(Model.Address)"

        LoadPin(center,title,address);
        map.setZoomLevel(14);
    }

    </script>
```

Comment: use like this: var latitude = @Model.Latitude;
        var longitude =@Model.Longitude;

Answer (score 1):

```
var latitude = Model.Latitude;
var longitude =Model.Longitude;
```

should be:

```
var latitude = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Latitude));
var longitude = @Html.Raw(Model.Longitude));
```

also this:

```
var title = "@Html.Encode(Model.Title)"
var address = "@Html.Encode(Model.Address)"
```

should be:

```
var title = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Title));
var address = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Address));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var latitude = @Model.Latitude;
var longitude = @Model.Longitude;
```